# How to print when NumberFormatException occurs?

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

How do I print something when a command line argument is not an integer and a `NumberFormatException` occurs?

My program takes 3 command line arguments and prints certain text depending on what they are.

Here's the code:

```
    public class CommandLine {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      if(args.length !=3){
          System.out.println("Error. Must give 3 values");
        }
     int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
     int y = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
     int z = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

     if((x%2)==0 && (y%2)==0 &&(z%2)==0)
     System.out.println("Even");

else
    System.out.println("odd");

  }

}
```

Comment: You need to catch the exception or throw it. Look at section 3.7.2 here: http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c3/s7.html. It shows an example of handling a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: use try catch to handle exceptions

Comment: Either catch the `NumberFormatException`, or test the content of an argument before parsing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       if(args.length !=3){
          System.out.println("Error. Must give 3 values");
        }
        else//if the above condition if true so skip these statements
        {
    try
    {
     int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
     int y = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
     int z = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

     if((x%2)==0 && (y%2)==0 &&(z%2)==0)
     System.out.println("Even");

    else
    System.out.println("odd");
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException ne)
    {
      System.out.println("Plz! pass only integer values");//catching number format exception
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can catch that exception and print :

```
int x=y=z=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
try{
   x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
   y = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
   z = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
}catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   System.out.println("x:" +x + " y:" +y +" z:" +z); 
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The first value which is still `Integer.MIN_VALUE` caused your exception(unless your number is `Integer.MIN_VALUE`)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you've done here with `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.  It's not in OP's code anywhere, were you using it to do some kind of experiment?

Comment: I just wanted to make it is easy for OP to recognise which variable caused error by looking at the value of x,y, z. I thought it will be helpful for OP this way instead of looking at stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
     public class CommandLine {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          if(args.length !=3){
              System.out.println("Error. Must give 3 values");
            }
         try{
         int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
         int y = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
         int z = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

         if((x%2)==0 && (y%2)==0 &&(z%2)==0)
         System.out.println("Even");

    else
        System.out.println("odd");


    }catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println("Exception Caught !");
    }
    }
}
```